# Can implied allegations be referenced without direct notability?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

There are a number of very common implications I hear often that I may want to ask a question on, but which are just indirect enough to be a little harder to find quotes for.  I'm wondering at what point are they common enough to not need to provide notability for.  To give examples, since I don't know a good way to better explain otherwise. Can I ask the below without direct a direct claim about the specific subset I'm asking about?

- Does the bible state lesbianism (not just gay men) is a sin.
- Do children raised by women who choose to conceive as a single mother less adapted then children of nuclear couples.

In the first example, I would have no trouble proving people say homosexuality is a sin because of statements in the bible.  I see plenty of people who are upset about lesbianism because it is a sin.  There is a clear impication that I feel is quite common that certain individuals believe the bible states that lesbinism is a sin.  However, I have a hard time finding a direct quote online where anyone explicitly says "there is a passage in the bible that says lesbian relationship are a sin".  Do I need that kind of notability for something that I think is pretty clearly implied by anti-homosexuality groups?

The second example is the less obvious one.  I have personally heard quite a few times people express that single mother's by choice will be unable to raise a child to be as fit as a couple, though part of that has to do with my volunteering in a community that has many single mother's by choice.  I know the general idea lingers in the community, but it's not as easy to find a quote specifically about single mothers by choice, because they aren't as common a topic discussed.  I can easily point to quotes about children of single parents *in general* struggling, and then specify that I consider single mother's who choose to conceive as a single parent is a different subset and that I am interested in the subgroup, or even point ou that people tend to take for granted that single parent homes struggle more then two parent homes.  Is that sufficient justification, or would such a claim still not be considered notable until I find an exact quote (which I no doubt could if I really looked)

Comment: Apropos nothing generic, there are definitive claims (and answers) regarding lesbianism and Old Testament on Judaism.SE. Which is really where this specific question belongs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *good idea* to find an exact quote for several reasons, including:

- If the source is popular, notability is established.
- If the OP is vague, we can look at context to establish the specifics of what the original claimant meant.
- If the OP has misunderstood the claim, we can look at exactly what was said to ensure we aren't tackling strawmen arguments.

However, it is **not** obligatory to include a notability reference. Just highly recommended.

---

That said, your two examples are problematic:

- The Bible's interpretation is highly opinion-based. [Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) is a much better site for trying to interpret the Bible. They use different set of rules for determining the truth - demanding empirical evidence isn't going to help this one.
- The criteria "less adapted" and "struggle more" are too vague. It isn't hard to come up with dozens of different measures that are likely to give different answers. There are also many confounding factors: Household income tends to be lower for single-parent families. Is it appropriate to separate out the effect of the lower income from the lack of a second parent's love? Depends on what the specific claim is.